# Need plot labels from separate column in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting number of people against the number of certain incidents per month, and need to plot each month's label on the side of each point in the plot. The labels are in a separate column (column 'month') and I need to find the synthax that can help me put the abbreviated 3-letter month label besides each associated point in the plot. I have done this in base plot previously but can't get it done in ggplot.

My script:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

new_labels <- c("1995-\n2001","2002-\n2011","2012-\n2019")

df %>%
  mutate(period=factor(period,levels = unique(period),
                   labels = new_labels,ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(people,inc)) +
    geom_point(cex=3.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,12,by=2),limit=c(0,12),expand=c(0,1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,75000,by=10000),limit=c(0,75000),expand=c(0,0)) +
    theme_bw(base_size=20) +
    facet_grid(class~category) +
    facet_grid(rows=vars(period)) +
    stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson"),col="black") +
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightgrey", size=1, color="black")) +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size=19, color="black",angle=0)) +
    labs(x = "Number of people per month", y = "Incidents per month")
```

My dataframe:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 
6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 
11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("APR", "AUG", "DEC", "FEB", "JAN", 
"JUL", "JUN", "MAR", "MAY", "NOV", "OCT", "SEP"), class = "factor"), 
people = c(4068L, 7251L, 14384L, 20513L, 18748L, 17760L, 
23433L, 22878L, 12815L, 8101L, 7477L, 5018L, 6830L, 16278L, 
30244L, 45747L, 31807L, 41184L, 54124L, 52565L, 24365L, 12759L, 
8307L, 6038L, 16711L, 32187L, 45810L, 53932L, 40082L, 58506L, 
71259L, 67564L, 33556L, 22818L, 16508L, 15848L), inc = c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried adding geom_text_repel(aes(label=month)), from the ggrepel package?

Comment: `geom_text(aes(label = month), vjust = -0.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +` or `ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = month)) +`

Comment: The first synthax leaves out labels that are too close, and the ggrepel-synthax returns the error message "Error in repel_boxes2(data_points = as.matrix(x$data[, c("x", "y")]),  : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'"

Comment: I reinstalled the Rcpp package and now this works!